# Return (\r) breaking cout

Tags: c++, windows, command-line, c++17, cout

std::cout prints extra characters in my keyPressed string, probably because of "\r", for example, if keyPressed = "Right arrow", when I press the up arrow, it prints "keyPressed = Up arrowoww", then, when I press right arrow again, it prints "keyPressed = Right arrow" normally again, but if I press any arrow key except "Right arrow" it prints some unwanted extra characters at the end

[Error example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctMFI.gif)

#### Source code:

game.cpp

```
#include "engine.h"
#include <iomanip>

Engine eng;

int main() {
    while (eng.isRunning) {
        eng.getInput();
        std::cout << std::setw(5);
        std::cout << "\r X = " << eng.playerX;
        std::cout << "| Y = " << eng.playerY;
        std::cout << "| KEY = " << eng.keyPressed;
        Sleep(100);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

engine.h

```
#ifndef ENGINE_H
#define ENGINE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

class Engine {
public:
    // Game
    bool isRunning = true;
    bool gettingInput = true;

    // Player
    int playerX = 1;
    int playerY = 1;
    char playerModel = 'P';

    // Test / Debug
    std::string keyPressed;

    // Functions
    char getInput() {
        // Gets arrow keys states
        while (this->gettingInput) {
            this->keyPressed = "";
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT)) {
                // Right arrow key
                this->playerX++;
                this->keyPressed = "Right arrow";
                break;
            }
            else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT)) {
                // Left arrow key
                this->playerX--;
                this->keyPressed = "Left arrow";
                break;
            }
            else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP)) {
                // Up arrow key
                this->playerY++;
                this->keyPressed = "Up arrow";
                break;
            }
            else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN)) {
                // Down arrow key
                this->playerY--;
                this->keyPressed = "Down arrow";
                break;
            }
            else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_END)) {
                exit(0);
            }
            Sleep(255);
        }
    }
};

#endif
```

Best / easiest way to fix this?
I searched and tested for 3 days but didn't find anything, please, help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're overwriting the previous output, when you print a shorter string the extra characters from the previous output are still displayed.  Replace the `\r` with a `\n` to see what's actually being output.

You can output some spaces after your key name to overwrite those extra characters with spaces and erase them.

Answer (score 0):

After looking over your provided code I do see a few issues or concerns with the code design: I'll break it down and explain some of the things that I see that could improve the quality of your code. I will start with your main.cpp then move on to your Engine class.

You initially have this:

> ```
> #include "engine.h"
> #include <iomanip>
>
> Engine eng;
>
> int main() {
>     while (eng.isRunning) {
>         eng.getInput();
>         std::cout << std::setw(5);
>         std::cout << "\r X = " << eng.playerX;
>         std::cout << "| Y = " << eng.playerY;
>         std::cout << "| KEY = " << eng.keyPressed;
>         Sleep(100);
>     }
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

The first main issue that I see is that you have declared `Engine eng` at the global level. We can fix this by

```
#include "engine.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    Engine eng; // declare it here as the first object in main; now it has local
                // scope within main's function and is now in Automatic Storage 
                // instead of Global Storage.
    while( ... ) {
        // ....
    }
    return 0;
};
```

---

The next issue starts with while loop's conditional expression in the main function.
You currently have:

> ```
> while( engine.isRunning ) { //... }
> ```

This is okay but this is more of an issue with your `Engine class's` design. Here you are providing a `public member` that anyone can access. So let's look at your class declaration/definition; you currently have:

> ```
> #ifndef ENGINE_H
> #define ENGINE_H
>
> #include <iostream>
> #include <Windows.h>
> #include <string>
>
> class Engine {
> public:
>     // Game
>     bool isRunning = true;
>     bool gettingInput = true;
>
>     // Player
>     int playerX = 1;
>     int playerY = 1;
>     char playerModel = 'P';
>
>     // Test / Debug
>     std::string keyPressed;
>
>     // Functions
>     char getInput() { // ... }
> };
>
> #endif
> ```

Here you should protect your data members and have access modifiers functions to them:

```
#ifndef ENGINE_H
#define ENGINE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

class Engine {
private:
    bool isRunning;
    bool gettingInput;

    // Player
    int playerX;
    int playerY;
    char playerModel;

    // Test / Debug
    std::string keyPressed;

 public:
    Engine() : 
      isRunning( false ),
      isGettingInput( false ),
      playerX( 1 ),
      playerY( 1 ),
      playerModel( 'P' ) 
    {}

    void run() { isRunning = true; // set or call other things here... }

    // Since we protected our members variables by making them private,
    // we now need some access functions to retrieve and modify them.
    bool isActive() const { return isRunning; } // make this const so it doesn't change anything
    void toggleIsActive() { isRunning = !isRunning; }

    bool retrievingInput() const { return isGettingInput; }
    void toggleRetrievingInput() { isGettingInput = !isGettingInput; } 

    int getPlayerX() const { return playerX; }
    void setPlayerX( int newX ) { playerX = newX; }

    int getPlayerY() const { return playerY; }
    void setPlayerY( int newY ) { playerY = newY; }

    // set both in one function call
    void setPlayerPosition( int newX, int newY ) {
        playerX = newX;
        playerY = newY;
    }

    char getPlayerModel() const { return playerModel; }
    // don't know if you want to change this: uncomment if you do
    // void setPlayerModel( char c ) { playerModel = c; }

    std::string& getPressedKey() const { return keyPressed; }

    char getInput() { // ... }
};
```

This should fix the interface design of your class. The only major difference here is that I had set your `Boolean` member variables to `false` by default because typically when you first start an `Engine` it is currently not already running. So to fix this we can call a public run function that will trigger this. So main would look like this instead:

```
int main () {
    Engine eng;
    eng.run(); // this now starts the engine sets the flag to true

    while (...) { //... }

    return 0;
}
```

---

However, I have also seen few concerns in your `Engine's` `getInput()` function, so let's take a look at it.

> ```
> char getInput() {
>     // Gets arrow keys states
>     while (this->gettingInput) {
>         this->keyPressed = "";
>         if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT)) {
>             // Right arrow key
>             this->playerX++;
>             this->keyPressed = "Right arrow";
>             break;
>         }
>         else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT)) {
>             // Left arrow key
>             this->playerX--;
>             this->keyPressed = "Left arrow";
>             break;
>         }
>         else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP)) {
>             // Up arrow key
>             this->playerY++;
>             this->keyPressed = "Up arrow";
>             break;
>         }
>         else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN)) {
>             // Down arrow key
>             this->playerY--;
>             this->keyPressed = "Down arrow";
>             break;
>         }
>         else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_END)) {
>             exit(0);
>         }
>         Sleep(255);
>     }
> }
> ```

The first part is the `while loop's` condition statement and your class's member. Originally you have this set to `true` by default, yet no where in the code did I see this value being updated. We don't need to change this but the fix is simple now that we have a way to change this member through a public interface call. Since I have made your `isGettingInput` `false` by default; you can now set this within this function before you enter the while loop. The only last issue that I see is that when this function is called back in `main's` while loop; this function never return's a value and the return value is never being used.

---

As to your actual problem with your bug for `cout` user : [1201programalarm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5231607/1201programalarm) has pretty much already answered that for you. Just thought I'd help you out a little bit more with your code.

Comment: I know that Stack Overflow tell people to not say "Thanks" in the comments, but, thanks man, really helped me and will help with future code.

Comment: @Pero I know but I do it too but not directly. I'd say something like: "I truly appreciate your feed back or positive criticism as it only helps me to be a more efficient programmer, software engineer."

Comment: @Pero They also say that I shouldn't give answers like I did above. I don't mind helping out where I can. It even helps me to improve my own skill sets. It also can serve as a great reference for future uses. I do it anyways since I'm purely self taught. When I first started to learn programming my first language(s) was a combination of C and C++. This was in the late 90s and early 2000s when information and resources were still limited. Yes the internet was a round; but most sites were text during the era of dial up and the beginning of high speed internet...

Comment: @Pero continued... Even pictures took a while to load onto the old style SVGA monitors (pre flat screen). They were also small in size if you had a 17 or 19 inch monitor you had a big monitor as most where only 9 - 15 inches... Resolution was horrible... if you had 1280 x 960 you were doing excellent. Videos were very rare and you couldn't just stream them you had to download them to watch it and hope you were able to play it. Sites like this and youtube weren't around yet and most online tutorials were all texts with only tidbits of examples that wouldn't compile...

Comment: @Pero continued... They didn't explain how to use the linker nor the debugger, the only things that were really available were mainly about the language(s) syntax, and concepts of the languages. I learned the hard way and here I am almost 20 years later and I'm still learning because the C++ language is evolving. I got into programming specifically for 3D Graphics Rendering, Animation, Physics Simulations etc. and I had to teach myself DirectX & OpenGL, and now I'm trying to learn CUDA and Vulkan. It's tough learning C++ but if you endure through it; it is well worth it!